# Portable ISR-safe data-passing

Tags: c, thread-safety, embedded, interrupt, isr

In embedded C, I'm trying to create a generic way to safely pass a value from my ISR (foreground) to my main loop (background).  By "generic" I mean I don't want to suspend interrupts (because that is compiler/CPU-specific and may have side effects), just want to do it with busy flags, etc.  For this particular mechanism I don't need a queue, I just want to retrieve the most recent value reported by the ISR.

So the pattern I'm using is a structure and a few functions that operate on the structure.  The issue of course is that the "write" function is ISR-based and can interrupt the "read" function at any time, and I want to remove the possibility of data corruption.  The approach is a two-slot system, and a couple of busy flags.

Will it work?  And/or is there a simpler way?  (Remember this is embedded C and I'm trying to be generic/portable.)  Thanks!

```
typedef struct 
{
    uint8_t busy;
    int32_t valueA; 
    int32_t valueB;     
    uint8_t reading_from_A;
    uint8_t last_wrote_to_B;
} sSafeI32_Fore2Back;

void SafeI32_InitFore2Back(sSafeI32_Fore2Back * si)
{
    si->busy = 0;    
    si->valueA = 0;
    si->valueB = 0;
    si->reading_from_A = 0;
    si->last_wrote_to_B = 1;
}

int32_t SafeI32_ReadFromBack(sSafeI32_Fore2Back * si)
{
    int32_t rtn;

    si->busy = 1;
    if (si->last_wrote_to_B)
    {
        rtn = si->valueB;
    }
    else
    {
        si->reading_from_A = 1;
        rtn = si->valueA;
        si->reading_from_A = 0;
    }
    si->busy = 0;

    return rtn;
}

void SafeI32_WriteFromFore(sSafeI32_Fore2Back * si, int32_t v)
{
    if (si->busy == 0)
    {
        si->valueA = v;
        si->last_wrote_to_B = 0;      
    }
    else
    {
        if (si->reading_from_A)
        {
            si->valueB = v;
            si->last_wrote_to_B = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            si->valueA = v;
            si->last_wrote_to_B = 0;            
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: It's common to use a circular queue of things.  The ISR loads data at a 'save' index and main loop extracts from a 'load' index when the 'save' index is different..  The ISR reads the 'save' index, moves it round one, loads in new data at that index and, when all that is safely done, stores the new value of index back into the 'save' index.  The main loop can then never see any new value of the 'save' index until the new data is fully available.  The indexes should be volatile.  If you had an RTOS, you would likely signal a semaphore upon which a handler thread awaits instead of polling.

Comment: Two things: I think a wrapping queue is not inherently threadsafe, for example if it is wider than 256 slots, then your indices are larger than a byte and it will take two assembly operations to read or write to them (ie its nonatomic).  Hence your modification of an index could occur after it is *halfway* read, producing a random result and bad behavior.

Comment: Second, a queue would produce slightly different behavior than what I'm going for above.  I want the *most recent* value from the ISR, no need for history -- if the previous one hasn't been read yet I want it to be overwritten.

Comment: Also thanks for the response :)

Comment: A wrapping queue is safe to use between one ISR and one thread/main loop as long as the protocol I describe above is followed.  The index is incremented and possibly wrapped in a temp, automatic var by the ISR, and data loaded in at this new index before the volatile 'save' var is set, so the thread/main cannot see any change in 'save' while the incrementing/testing/setting is happening in an automatic var.   It's fine - I've used such a scheme many times and, as long as the setting of the 'save' is done last, it's OK.  Can fail with a) nested ISRs b) More than one thread waiting.

Answer (score 0):

I performed a code walk-though and could not find any glaring issue with the implemention.  I believe it would work safely.  However, it is probably overly complex with the use of the two flags (busy and reading_from_A) which made it a bit more challenging to review. The important part is that only the background function writes to the flags (reading_from_A and the busy) and not the foreground function.

below shows a possible simplification that I believe will also safely work. I have used a similar implementation on an 8051 processor.

```
typedef struct
{
    uint8_t pendingData;
    uint8_t index;
    int32_t value[2];
} sSafeI32_Fore2Back;

void SafeI32_InitFore2Back(sSafeI32_Fore2Back * si)
{
    si->pendingData = 0;
    si->index = 0;
    si->value[0] = 0;
    si->value[1] = 0;
}

int32_t SafeI32_ReadFromBack(sSafeI32_Fore2Back * si)
{
    if (si->pendingData) {
        if (si->index == 0) {
            si->index = 1;
        } else {
            si->index = 0;
        }
        si->pendingData = 0;
    }
    return si->value[index];


    // Note 1: you could change the above if;then;else to
    //  index = (index+1) % 2;
    // but this is not an atomic operation and the ISR could
    // fire after the sum and before the modulo 2.
    // Perhaps index would take on an intermediate value of 2 before
    // the modulo and lead to a memory corruption by indexing out of
    // range when the ISR fires.  The ISR could mask the upper bits out
    // to ensure an out of range condition does not occur, but I think
    // the if;then;else is inherently safer.

    // Note 2: You need to assume that the ISR has fired at least once before this
    // function is called. Otherwise the function will return the initialized
    // value of 0. I believe the original post would do the same....

    // Note 3: I believe the original post is correct (at least I didn't find any
    // glaring issue with it.)  The important part is that only the background
    // function writes to the flags (reading_from_A and the busy) and not the
    // foreground function. Likewise, in this implemention, only the background
    // write to index and the forground function only reads it.However, the
// pendingData flag is read and written by both functions. Note that it is
// only written if its in a particular state which is mutually exclusive
}

void SafeI32_WriteFromFore(sSafeI32_Fore2Back * si, int32_t v)
{
    si->value[(si->index + 1) % 2] = v;  // write to the other location than what is
                                         // is being read from.
    if (!si->pendingData) {
        si->pendingData = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome!  Looks great, thanks will compare/contrast.

Comment: Question, say the ISR writes a '3' to it, then I read from it it will get a '3'.  Then I read from it again I will get a '0', right?  That's a little different than the intent (which I didn't explain very well, sorry) of always getting the most recent value.  (In other words we want to retrieve '3' until it is overwritten, like a simple variable.)

Comment: Yes.  I think you would get a 0 on the next read if the ISR did not fire in between.

Comment: Probably would need to add a counter like the other suggestion to know if a new value had been written.

Comment: I fixed the error you pointed out with regards to the multiple reads.  But I added another flag which brings it basically back to what you implemented. Its a little bit different and maybe a little bit simpler.

Answer (score 0):

One simple, common way of doing this is by having the read function ensure it wasn't preempted during the read. The ISR updates a counter each time it executes and the read function ensures that the counter didn't change during access. If the counter did change, the read is performed again.

```
typedef struct
{
    int32_t value;
    uint32_t counter;
} sSafeI32_Fore2Back;

void SafeI32_InitFore2Back(volatile sSafeI32_Fore2Back * si)
{
    si->value = 0;
    si->counter = 0;
}

int32_t SafeI32_ReadFromBack(volatile sSafeI32_Fore2Back * si)
{
    int32_t rtn;
    uint32_t ctr;

    do {
        ctr = si->counter;
        rtn = si->value;
    } while(ctr != si->counter);

    return rtn;
}

void SafeI32_WriteFromFore(sSafeI32_Fore2Back * si, int32_t v)
{
    si->value = v;
    si->counter++;
}
```

Comment: Why use a counter? Seems needlessly complex, since you can just use any volatile bool variable. Reader: `changed = false; x = read; if(changed)...`.

Comment: @Lundin I agree that your solution is cleaner when there is only a single background task. But restricting state changes to ISR execution makes the read thread-safe.

Comment: If you have multiple threads communicating directly with the same ISR, the design is bad. It should be ISR <-> driver <-> driver setter/getter <-> multiple threads.

Comment: @Lundin Isn't the read function pretty much an implementation of a driver getter?

Answer (score 0):

Since you know that an interrupt cannot get interrupted in turn (unless you have some special exotic scenario), it is pretty simple:

```
static volatile bool changed = false;
static uint32_t value;

void isr (void) // it is an interrupt; it can't be interrupted by the caller
{
  changed = true;
  value = something;
}

void caller (void)
{
  ...
  changed = false;
  uint32_t val = value;
  if(changed)
  {
    // handle error, discard val
  }
}
```

The `changed` variable need not even have atomic access.

Note however that all variables shared between an ISR and the caller must be `volatile` or all manner of weird and very subtle optimization bugs may strike.